# How can I control default namespace in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to write a web service to integrate with a 3rd party application and one of their requirements is to make sure that the default namespace = “http://tempuri.org/".

How can I set my namespace in Web API?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("MyTestMethod")]
    public void TestMethod(XmlDocument myXml)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInfo("myXML = " + myXml);
            myXml.Save(@"C:\MyTestFile.xml");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you will  do  better if you change the title of your question if you  mean  to  insert the namespace in the xmldocument

Comment: Their requirement is: When creating a Web Service, use the default namespace: “http://tempuri.org/".

Comment: What do you mean by namespace ? do you mean URL?

Comment: That is my assumption.  What I sent was straight from their documentation.

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve? can you please tell me.

Comment: Ultimately I am trying to configure my method based on their documentation.  I know the application is calling the method from my log messages, however the XmlDocument "myXml" is always null.  I was going over their documentation and I set everything accordingly with the exception of: "When creating a Web Service, use the default namespace: http://tempuri.org/"

Comment: Can you give me a link of documentation, are you talking about. how you post `XmlDocument`file

Comment: See edit... That is all I have to go on.

Comment: Dear JDS, by mistake you get it wrongly, that first line mean you should set api on this url like : `http://testpuri.org/api/controllername/methodname` that you have to set in route file

Comment: And you cannot post data in this way in WebApi, that is the reason why you get null values

Comment: ty I created a quick asmx and it worked.  (Would prefer if I could go restful)

Comment: *Would prefer if I could go restful* That is also good option, but it doesn't providing  routing and other option which WebApi provided. But again it's also good option and you can go through it. Hope this helps!